# If statement not operating properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
xl = []
while True:
    x = raw_input("enter ")
    xl.append(x)
    if "1" in xl and "2" in xl and "3" in xl:
        print "yay"
    elif "3"in xl and"4"in xl and"5"in xl :
        print "yay"
```

I want it so that the program will only print "yay" once ALL the criterias are met but that doesn't happen:

```
enter 1
enter 2
enter 3
yay
enter 4
yay
enter 5
yay
```

As you can see I hadn't even put 3,4,5 in sequence and I got a "yay". how do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You didn't clear the `xl` list, so `1`, `2` and `3` are *still in the list*.

Comment: and he prints `yay` in both branches ... so ...

Comment: And the question is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the `if`-statement.

You have to clear your sequence once you have found three numbers that cause a "yay".
Else, the criteria will continue to be met once you got there.
So after the `print` you need a `xl.remove('1')`, etc.